# How to build up a Linq to Sql where clause bit by bit?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am being passed a set of querystring parameters within a Parameters class with which to query an image database. With each call some parameters may by null. So in sql I would build up the query like

```
if (parameters.Value1 != null)
{
    sql.Append("sql_where_clause");
}

if (parameters.Value2 != null)
{
    sql.Append("sql_where_clause");
}
```

How do I do the same using Linq?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

easy, IQueryables aren't evaluated until you enumerate, so simply keep tagging on where clauses.

```
if (parameters.Value1 != null)
{
    results = results.Where(x => <some condition>);
}

if (parameters.Value2 != null)
{
    results = results.Where(x => <some other condition>);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The best way to dynamically build where-clauses is to use the wonderful Albahari [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

You can use this to build where-clause expressions containing `OR` as well as `AND`. Language-integrated support for this was originally intended but [didn't quite make](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/f79d7065-a3b7-47ad-a02f-44858b8ad3b6/) it into C# 3.

For example:

```
var whereClause = PredicateBuilder.False<Customer>();

if (parameters.Value1 != null)
{
    whereClause = whereClause.Or(customer => customer.City == parameters.Value1);
}

var query = db.Customers.Where(whereClause);
```

Comment: This made/saved my day.  Thanks.  
And I was thinking that I just didnt get Linq to sql, as I just started using it..but alas the link above to PredicateBuilder was great! :)  This definately is something that should be there??