# How concat where in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have structure ifs:

```
if()
{
  query = query.Where(....)
}

if()
{
   query = query.Where(....)
}
```

as they do to these two tests work together, and do not overwrite each other?

Comment: You can add && operator within Where claus

Comment: -1. Please word ur question properly

Comment: @nawfal - Yes, like using 'your' instead of 'ur'.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to complete a where clause according to external conditions? (like for instance if "the user is anonymous" his search will be further restricted)

Comment: Hi, your question is getting downvoted because it is very poorly worded and no effort has been made. Try to improve it and you will get a better response

Comment: "*do not overwrite each other*" - The queries aren't "overwriting" eachother they are "chaining" together, what you are doing is fine considering you have specific conditions to chain. It's the equivalent of doing `query.Where(...).Where(...)`.

Comment: See [How to build up a Linq to Sql where clause bit by bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898286/how-to-build-up-a-linq-to-sql-where-clause-bit-by-bit), [VB.Net Linq - How to append a where clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782566/vb-net-linq-how-to-append-a-where-clause), and [How do I implement a dynamic 'where' clause in LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001462/how-do-i-implement-a-dynamic-where-clause-in-linq).

Answer (score 2):

> as they do to these two tests work together, and do not overwrite each other?

Your code will (depending on the outcome in the `if()`s) chain the queries.

The final result will be that all `.Where(...)` s are applied to the source.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to chain your query expression:

```
query = query.Where(....).Where(....);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have some flexibility in predicate creation, I'd suggest [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). With this library you can build your `Where` clause dynamically, to get, for example:

```
if(condition)
{
   predicate.And(something);
}
if(otherCondition)
{
   predicate.Or(somethingElse);
}
var result = source.Where(predicate);
```

It has open source code, very easy to understand, basing on `Expression` class, which is actually used by Linq.

It's also worth noticing, that the result is computed only when it's needed - so it's a good solution to create a condition for Linq2SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
var flg1 = cond1 == null? true : cond1;
var flg2 = cond2 == null? true : cond2;

var result = query.Where(flg1 && flg2)
```

You also can use the [DynamicQuery library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Then you can use like

```
query.Where("field1=1 and field2=2");
```

Comment: Please show how this is going to work when `cond1` and `cond2` are sql conditions that refer to data tables used in the query.